# Create a log in screen on iOS that will always show on top of all views

Tags: ios, authentication, modalviewcontroller

EDIT: Check below for solution.

I am working on a login screen for my app and I have it working for the most part except for a few edge cases. Ive set things up so that I have a segue from my UITabBar in the story board that I trigger in the app delegate applicationDidBecomeActive: method. As I said it works fine on all but one edge case I've found so far.

My app uses some modal view controllers, some of which are UIActivityViewControllers if that makes a difference, to enter and edit some core data entities. If one of these modal view controllers is opened when the app goes to the background, it will always show up when the app is reopened and my login doesn't show. I get the following console msg

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: 0x1d51e320>  on <MPTabBarViewController: 0x1d5b4810> which is already presenting <UIActivityViewController: 0x1e38fc40>
```

Here is my code

```
   - (void) displayLogin{
        NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

        NSDate *lastDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:MPLastCloseDate];
        NSTimeInterval timeDiff = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDate];
        int seconds = timeDiff;

        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:MPPassCodeDelay] == MPScreenLockAlways || seconds >= 300) {
            NSLog(@"Should see login");
            [tabBarController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginScreen" sender:self];
        }
    }
```

I understand exactly what this msg is telling me, the tab bar is already presenting a modal controller so it can't present another one. So my question is this, Is there a better way to implement this so that the login will always show, even over top of the modal views?

---

### **Okay here is my current solution**

as suggested by Bartu and requested to be shared by Shawn

I have a working singleton loginManager class that requires 1 call in app delegate and 1 call in any view controller that could be called to present as modal. I was unable to figure out how to do this as suggested with a ViewController category, but hey a few includes and method calls aren't so bad. I included it in App-Prefix.pch, so its available everywhere. It is written for ARC, so if you like managing your own memory you'll need to modify the singleton for that. The last caveat, at current you will need to roll your own viewController for the login screen. Just look for the commented section in the implementation with all the stars, and put your own view controller there. Mine is still in my app storyboard, its basically 4 digit pin that checks for a match in the keychain and dismisses itself for the correct pin. I may pull that out of my storyboard and nib it so it could be packaged with the loginManager and let it become my first gitHub project at some future date though.

You can configure it to display login for every time the app opens or after a delay with properties. The delay time is also a property set in seconds. It will also block out your apps UI for the few seconds it takes to get the login displayed with a splash using your apps Default.png. This is also configurable with a property.

I would love to get some feedback on this, and if anyone can tell me how to do a category so the extra call in viewControllers is not needed that would be great! Enjoy!

**AppDelegate:**

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // these calls are all optional
    [[VHLoginManager loginManager] setShouldBlockUIWithSplashOnResume:NO];
    [[VHLoginManager loginManager] setSecondsRequiredToPassBeforeLockDown:1000];
    [[VHLoginManager loginManager] setScreenLockRequirment:VHLMScreenLockDelayed];

    // this is the only required call to run with defaults - always login and block UI with splash while login loads
    [[VHLoginManager loginManager] presentLogin];
}
```

**Any viewController that may presented as modal at some point**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[VHLoginManager loginManager] registerViewControllerIfModal:self];
}
```

**The loginManager class**

header:

```
//  VHLoginManager.h
//  Created by Victor Hudson on 5/31/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Victor Hudson. All rights reserved.
//  Use if you like but be nice and leave my name 

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#define VHLMLastCloseDate @"VHLMLastCloseDate"
#define VHLMPassCodeDelay @"VHLMPassCodeDelay"

typedef enum {
    VHLMScreenLockAlways = 0,
    VHLMScreenLockDelayed = 1,
} VHLMScreenLockRequirement;

@interface VHLoginManager : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldBlockUIWithSplashOnResume;
// defaults to yes so app contents arent visible before the login screen appears
@property (nonatomic) int secondsRequiredToPassBeforeLockDown;
// defaults to 5 minutes (300)

#pragma mark - Class Methods
+ (VHLoginManager *)loginManager;
// returns the singleton login manager

#pragma mark - Manager Methods
- (void) presentLogin;
// will determine if login should be presented an do so if needed
- (void) registerViewControllerIfModal:(UIViewController *)controller;
// any view controllers that are presented modally should call this with self as controller in viewDidLoad - the pupose of this manager is so login shows even over top of modals
- (void) setScreenLockRequirment:(VHLMScreenLockRequirement) requirement;
// deafaults to always if not adjusted
@end
```

implementation:

```
//  VHLoginManager.m
//  Created by Victor Hudson on 5/31/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Victor Hudson. All rights reserved.
//  Use if you like but be nice and leave my name

#import "VHLoginManager.h"
static VHLoginManager *loginManager = nil;

@interface VHLoginManager ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *currentModalViewController;
@property (nonatomic) VHLMScreenLockRequirement screenLockrequirement;
@end

@implementation VHLoginManager
#pragma mark - Manager Methods
- (void) presentLogin
{
    // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:VHLMPassCodeDelay] == VHLMScreenLockAlways || [self timeSinceLastClose] >= self.secondsRequiredToPassBeforeLockDown) {
        //NSLog(@"User should see login");
        // determine who the presenting view controller should be
        UIViewController *viewController;
        if (self.currentModalViewController && self.currentModalViewController.presentingViewController != nil) {
            // NSLog(@"We have a modal view controller on top");
            viewController = self.currentModalViewController;
        } else {
            // NSLog(@"We have NO modal view controller on top");
            // get the root view controller of the app
            viewController = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
        }

//********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
        // *** This is still tied into my app storyboard and should be made into a viewcontroller with nib to be portable with loginManager for now implement and present your own loginViewController
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        UINavigationController *navController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"appLoginScreen"];
//********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

        // present the login to user
        [viewController presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void) setScreenLockRequirment:(VHLMScreenLockRequirement) requirement
{
    _screenLockrequirement = requirement;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:self.screenLockrequirement forKey:VHLMPassCodeDelay];
}

- (void) registerViewControllerIfModal:(UIViewController *)controller
{
    // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (controller.presentingViewController) {
        NSLog(@"Registering a modalViewController");
        self.currentModalViewController = controller;
    }
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (void) timeStampForBackground
{
    // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:VHLMLastCloseDate];
    [self setDisplaySplashForBackgroundResume];
}

- (int) timeSinceLastClose
{
    return [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:VHLMLastCloseDate]];
}

#pragma mark Splash Screen management
- (void) setDisplaySplashForBackgroundResume
{
    // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (self.shouldBlockUIWithSplashOnResume) {
        // dismiss all keyboards and input views
        UIView *topView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
        [topView endEditing:YES];

        // Don't show a splash screen if the application is in UIApplicationStateInactive (lock/power button press)
        UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            UIImageView *splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
            splash.frame = application.keyWindow.bounds;
            [application.keyWindow addSubview:splash];
        }
    }
}

- (void) removeSplashScreen
{
    // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (self.shouldBlockUIWithSplashOnResume) { // we should have a splash image up if true
                                                // so remove it
        UIWindow *thewindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        if ([[thewindow subviews] count] > 1) {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
            [[[thewindow subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
#pragma mark - Class Management

//prevent additional instances
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self loginManager];
}

+ (VHLoginManager *)loginManager
{
    if (!loginManager) {
        //Create The singleton
        loginManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }

    return loginManager;
}

- (id) init
{
    // If we already have an instance of loginManager
    if (loginManager) {
        //Return The Old One
        return loginManager;
    }

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(timeStampForBackground)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                   object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(removeSplashScreen)
                                                     name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                                   object:nil];
        self.shouldBlockUIWithSplashOnResume = YES;
        self.secondsRequiredToPassBeforeLockDown = 300;

        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:VHLMPassCodeDelay]) {
            [self setScreenLockRequirment:VHLMScreenLockAlways];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a short time ago, my solution for this problem is to have a reference to any modal view which is currently presented in your app delegate. So, you can know if your tab bar controller is already presenting a modal controller and if it's the case, you can present your login view over your current modal view.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be more MVC if instead of an appDelegate reference to the modals they just listened for the delegate msg notifications and responded to them?

Comment: sound much more like MVC :) even better you can create a singleton to listen for notifications and manages presentation of your login view. Which will also make your login view controller's mechanism portable.

Comment: So to do that the singleton class would have to track open modal views and then trigger them based on the notifications correct? Forgive me. I'm not a complete newb but still a rookie;-)

Comment: If you do that it would be very nice if you could post your code ! I'm still a rookie too, and a real MVC solution could be instructive. Thanks.

Comment: @Agent00Vic totally! it wouldn't be so complicated. You only have to track open modal views when they start up (maybe you can add a category UIViewController+ModalNotifications) and import this category for whichever modal view controller that will notify your singleton, and you will act on this notifications on your singleton :)

Comment: Thanks Bartu! One last question and I'll let you go. I'm not too  familiar with categories yet. If I understand correctly, I could use them to add a method to UIViewController Class so that it automagically registers with my singleton when presented as modal? @Shawn I'll play with this sometime in the next few days. If I get a workable implementation I'll amend my original post to include it.

Comment: Great that you found a solution to your problem. If you are looking to employ a log in view for your iOS app, suggest using a `BALogInView`. It's easy to set up and makes for quick development. https://github.com/brandonaskea/BALogInView

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to have a switch in my appDelegate. when the app started, if the user had not logged in, I created the login view and make it the window's rootViewController. When the user successfully logged in, I used an animation block to set that view's alpha to 0, then created a UITabBarController, populated it, made it the window's rootViewController (with an alpha of 0, then animated it's alpha to 1). Worked really well. Not sure how to do this with storyboards though.

EDIT: now getting familiar with storyboards. So what you would do is not use the Main.storyboard per se (remove it from info.plist), then add a LoginViewController as a view, and have your UITabbarController there too - but nothing is the initial view controller. You obviously have to name each view so you can create it in code, but asking the Storyboard to create such and such a view controller

So in App Delegate, if logged in, instantiate the tab bar controller and add it as the root view controller. If the user has not logged in, create the LoginView and add it as rootview controller. If the user does login, have some method on the LoginViewController so it can ask the delegate to switch to the tab bar controller.

Comment: awesome, every other answer was to use modal but this works really well. +1

Comment: @RobR., using Storyboards now in Xcode 5, I edited the answer to provide guidance on how to do the answer with storyboards.